# How to detect time of Notification received?

Tags: android, notifications

I have an application in which i have to store each notification recieved time in sharedpreference.I searched a lot but didn't find any solution.Please let me know if there is any possibility to do this type of issue.

code:-

```
 public void customNotification(String title, String message,int image) {
    // Using RemoteViews to bind custom layouts into Notification
    RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification_card);
    builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(intent)
    //Create Intent to launch this Activity again if the notification is clicked.
    Intent i = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, i,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    builder.setContentIntent(intent);
            // Set Icon
    builder .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.snap);
            // Dismiss Notification
    builder .setAutoCancel(true);
    builder .setOngoing(true);
            // Set RemoteViews into Notification
    builder.setContentIntent(intent);
    builder.setContent(remoteViews);

    // Locate and set the Image into customnotificationtext.xml ImageViews
    remoteViews.setImageViewResource(R.id.imagenotileft,image);

    // Locate and set the Text into customnotificationtext.xml TextViews
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.title,title);
    remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.text,message);

    // Create Notification Manager
    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    // Build Notification with Notification Manager
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());

}
```

Comment: How do you send notification, post code here.

Comment: So what is the problem? Store your time in your notification receiver class.

Comment: I don't know how to store

Answer (score 0):

When you calling this method notification is going to post in status bar so in this method save the time like sample as follows

```
  SharedPreference sharePref=sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("notification_time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharePref.edit();
  edit.putLong("time_"+title,System.currentTimeMills());
  edit.apply();
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the bottom of your method.
For taking the time like:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
String currentDateAndTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

and then for save it to sharedPreference:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

//for the id
int id = preferences.getInt("notification_received_time_id",0);
id += 1;
editor.putInt("notification_received_time_id",id);

//for the value

editor.putString("notification_received_time",currentDateAndTime);
editor.apply();
```

to access it (from anywhere else) call this code:

```
notification_received_time_id = 1; //whichever id you want

SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String notificationReceivedTime = preferences.getString(notification_received_time_id, "");
```

Comment: and How to make difference between current date and time and date and time saved in Shred preference